# How to kill of all turtles except for one?

Tags: netlogo

Im making a race model. the function is that the turtles move across the grid horizontally starting at xcor -13 to xcor 13 at speeds that
constantly vary and when a turtle reaches xcor = 13, all of the other turtles (besides the one that crossed first) die

```
 to Race
    wait .3
    fd random 5
    if xcor = 13  ( this is where i want to tell all other turtles to die )
 end
```

how do i ask all other turtles to die?
THe first answer doesnt help me, someone else please respond

Comment: What's not helpful about the first answer? No clue what you're looking for if "ask other turtles [ die ]" isn't it.

Comment: I really don't know what exactly you are looking for! If you can explain more I might be able to change my answer :)

Comment: If your problem is with my complete example which might make it difficult to understand just use 'if xcor = 13  [ask other turtles [die]]'

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by asking the winner to ask other turtles [die]

```
 to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks  
  ;resize-world min-pxcor max-pxcor min-pycor max-pycor 
  resize-world -15 20 0 3
  set-patch-size 15
  ;set-patch-size size 
  create-turtles 10
  [setxy -13 1 set heading 90 set shape "car" wait 0.3]
  ask patch -13 2 [Set plabel "Start" set pcolor 110] ; just for visualization
  ask patch 13 2 [Set plabel "END" set pcolor 110]
end


to go
  ifelse count turtles > 1 
  [
  ask turtles
  [Race]
  ]
  [stop]

  tick
end
to Race
  fd random 5
    if xcor >= 13   [ set size 2 ask other turtles [die] ]
 end
```

This is a sample screenshot

[image: Start]

[image: END]

I really low examples, so there is another way to improve visualization of the race by having multiple lines of cars:

```
 resize-world -15 20 0 5
  set-patch-size 15
  create-turtles 20
  [set xcor -13 set ycor one-of [0 1 2 3 4 ] set heading 90 set shape "car" ]
  ask patch -13 5 [Set plabel "Start" set pcolor 110]
  ask patch 13 5 [Set plabel "END" set pcolor 110]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you use xcor = 13 , some turtles might jump and cross the line,  so I think its safer to use  xcor >= 13

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do doesn't make much sense. When posting, please make sure that the question provides a better context for answering you question.

My interpretation of your question is that the cars don't matter at all. All you want to figure out is that when one turtle crosses the finish line, you kill all the other turtles.

Doing so I would probably give each turtle a property of a name or label. Store them all in an array.

Then if the turtle crosses the finish line, remove all the turtles from the array except for

```
if turtle.name == turtle[i].name.
```

Hope that helps. Please be a little more clear next time.

Comment: i edited it to make more sense. im not sure how to use arrays yet, is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

You need a way to identify the living turtle and kill the other turtles. To do this, you could either write a ton of if statements but it would look horrible.

```
 if(larry.coordinates == 13){
      kill(tom);
      kill(harry);
```

}

Your best bet would be to read how to create an array. Store it in an array. Trust me, arrays are pretty simple.